# how to return 1000 variables from a function in C?

Tags: c

How to return 1000 variables from a function in C?
This is an interview question asked which I was unable to answer.

I guess with the help of pointers we can do that. I am new to pointers and C can anyone give me solution to solve this problem either using pointers or different approach?

Comment: 1000 variables or 1000 values from the same type?

Comment: Laugh in their face. If they're serious about it, RUN.

Comment: @cnicutar - hahahahah, +1, you're damn right.

Comment: @KirilKirov I don't know what they meant here with `variables`, I guess variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pack them all in a structure and return the structure.

```
struct YourStructure
{
    int a1;
    int b2;

    int z1000;
};

YouStructure doSomething();
```

Comment: A name cannot start with a digit in C and C++ :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's 1000 times the same type (e.g. int's):

```
void myfunc(int** out){
  int i = 0;
  *out  = malloc(1000*sizeof(int));
  for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    (*out)[i] = i;
  }
}
```

This function allocates memory for 1000 integers (an array of integers) and fills the array.

The function would be called that way:

```
int* outArr = 0;
myfunc(&outArr);
```

The memory held by `outArr` must be freed after use:

```
free(outArr);
```

See it running on ideone: http://ideone.com/u8NX5

---

Alternate solution: instead of having `myfunc` allocate the memory for the integer array, let the caller do the work and pass the array size into the function:

```
void myfunc2(int* out, int len){
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
    out[i] = i;
  }
}
```

Then, it's called that way:

```
int* outArr = malloc(1000*sizeof(int));
myfunc2(outArr, 1000);
```

Again, the memory of `outArr` must be freed by the caller.

---

Third approach: static memory. Call `myfunc2` with static memory:

```
int outArr[1000];
myfunc2(outArr, 1000);
```

In that case, no memory has to be allocated or freed.

Comment: Kindly explain what purpose `return;` fills. If you can give a rational explanation, I'll totally up-vote.

Comment: @Lundin: you're right. The `return` is not needed. Editing answer.

Answer (score 1):

Array Pointer approach:

```
int * output(int input)
{
    int *temp=malloc(sizeof(int)*1000);
    // do your work with 1000 integers
    //...
    //...
    //...
    //ok. finished work with these integers
    return temp;
}
```

Struct pointer approach:

```
struct my_struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    double x;
    ...
    //1000 different things here
    struct another_struct;
}parameter;


my_struct * output(my_struct what_ever_input_is)
{
    my_struct *temp=malloc(sizeof(my_struct));
    //...
    //...
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Also memory leak approach. Let the caller allocate the memory instead and pass the pointer as a parameter.

Comment: you are right. But is another way. This way exists. And this is just an interview.

Comment: That would be one more reason to prevent such stuff if possible

Comment: But if the pointer by malloc() is freed then it is not a leak anymore

Comment: Yes, but functions that have nothing to do with memory allocation, yet doing so, expecting someone else to to clean up their mess, is the source of memory leaks in 9 cases out of 10. I realize this was just a "quick & dirty" example, but why should a function called "output" allocate dynamic memory and return it to the caller? Such a program design doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If programmer already uses pointers to a structure or array, he/she already in a situation of managing garbages am i right? PAssing those pointers as a parameter doesnt say that pointer will not be needed to garbage collected. If i am not right, can you give me sample that uses pointer as parameter and does not need any garbage collection of 1000 variables

Comment: But, you are right if the programmer and the function giver are not the same person :D

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it in C.

```
void func (Type* ptr);
/*
   Function documentation.
   Bla bla bla...

   Parameters
   ptr      Points to a variable of 'Type' allocated by the caller. 
            It will contain the result of...

*/
```

If your intention wasn't to return anything through "ptr", you would have written

```
void func (const Type* ptr);
```

instead.